# Closure vs. nested function

Tags: python, closures

Can somebody explain me, what is difference between closure function and nested function? Both of them are inside the outer function, but I don't get that difference between them.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as a "closure function". There *is* something called a "closure", though.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't python nested functions called closures?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4020419)

Comment: Closure function is function inside outer function, which has access to the variables of outer function, even if outer_function has finished.

Comment: @QClodd: those are called nested functions too. There is no such term, really.

Comment: @QClodd: and the access is limited to *specific variables*, not all variables. The closure is the structure that maintains those specific variables.

Comment: So variables which can access inner function from outer function are called closures, okay?

Comment: @QClodd: I've clarified my answer: the closure is the namespace / object / *thing* holding on to the variables to ensure they continue to exist when the local namespace of the outer function is gone. The variables are referred to as 'free variables' in terms of the inner function, or closure cells when talking about the closure.

Comment: Perfect ... thank for your time and willingness ... really good explanation bro

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference, because there are no *closure function*, not really. There are [*closures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), but that term refers to the technique of preserving variables used in both the outer and inner scopes. All you are left with are *nested functions*.

A nested function is just a function defined inside another:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        # ...
    # ...
```

When `outer()` defines a name that `inner()` then *also* uses, then *that variable name* is called a closure cell, stored in the closure environment for `inner`:

```
def outer():
    variable_in_outer = some_value
    another_variable = some_other_value
    def inner():
        expression using variable_in_outer
        # ...
    # ...
```

Here `variable_in_outer` is *closed over* by `inner()`, thus creating a closure. If `inner()` has a life beyond `outer` (because `inner` is returned, for example, to the caller of `outer()`), then you can't just clean up `variable_in_outer` like you would other local variables. `another_variable` is any other variable in `outer` that isn't used by a nested function; it's just another local variable and is cleaned up when `outer()` ends.

So a closure is created to 'keep variables alive' as it were, until `inner()` is gone too. The closure holds the `variable_in_outer` closure cell, and any other such closed-over variables, as long as `inner` needs them.

Deciding what names are closed over happens at compile time. You can introspect closures via the `__closure__` attribute on a function object, a tuple of closure cells, each with a `cell_contents` attribute that lets you access the current value of the variable. If there are no closures, `__closure__` is set to `None`:

```
>>> def outer():
...     variable_in_outer = 42
...     another_variable = 81
...     def inner():
...         return variable_in_outer
...     return inner  # return the inner function object
...
>>> nested = outer()
>>> nested
<function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x106a46c80>
>>> nested.__closure__
(<cell at 0x1069adfa8: int object at 0x1055adfe0>,)
>>> nested.__closure__[0].cell_contents
42
>>> outer.__closure__ is None  # outer has no closed-over variables.
True
```

Because the compiler decides what is a closure and what is not, you can introspect the code objects to see what names are used for closures:

```
>>> outer.__code__.co_cellvars
('variable_in_outer',)
>>> outer.__code__.co_consts[3]  # code object used to create `inner` functions
<code object inner at 0x106703660, file "<stdin>", line 3>
>>> outer.__code__.co_consts[3].co_freevars
('variable_in_outer',)
```

`co_cellvars` are the names of variables that become closures, `co_freevars` the references that use those closures.

Comment: So basically speaking ... the variables inside outer function is closure for inner function. And the benefit of this is that inner function can keep variable from outer function even if outer function has finished. Am I right?

Comment: @QClodd: exactly, because local variables are normally removed from memory when a function ends.

Comment: wow, thank you Martijn ... I have read 2 tutorials and they were talking about closures as the inner function. Now I fully understand that. I have one more request on you. Can you give me some example of variable, which is inside outer function, but it 's not closure (inner function cannot store that). Thank you

Comment: @QClodd: just add more variables to `outer` that `inner` doesn't use.

Comment: Ahhh, so basically, variables in outer function, which inner function does not use are not closures? If I am right, that was simpler than I thought :)

Comment: @QClodd: any variable not used by an inner function is just another local variable, and thus not part of the closure. The closure object doesn't need to care about those, and no cells are created for them.

Comment: Yea, so closure namespace holds only those variables, which needs inner function. Others are deleted from memory after outer function was called.